# How is the following long exact sequence constructed?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I don't know how the following long exact sequence is constructed

[image]

According to Bredon's "Topology and Geometry", it follows from the fact that $0\to A'\to A\to A''\to 0$ is a short exact sequence, and that $G$ has an injective resolution. Also, for each injective group $I$, $0\to \text{Hom}(A'',I)\to \text{Hom}(A,I)\to \text{Hom}(A',I)\to 0$ is an exact sequence. However, I don't know how these facts lead to the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the long exact sequence associated to a short exact sequence of chain complexes, then recall how the Ext groups are defined.

Comment: Ext groups are defined in the following way: Let $G\to I\to I'\to 0$ be an injective resolution of $G$. Then we have $0\to \text{Hom}(A,G')\to \text{Hom}(A,G)\to \text{Hom}(A,G'')\to Ext(A,G)\to 0$.

Comment: I still don't understand how the sequence given in my question is constructed. Maybe we're trying to construct a long exact sequence of homology or cohomology groups from a short exact sequence of chain complexes, but I don't see how

Comment: You should look at a homological algebra text then. Classics are Weibel, but honestly the AT notes by Kirk and Davis have a good (short) introduction to Tor and Ext groups.

Comment: I'm going to assume you don't mean that in a facetious, but only in a helpful way. I'm familiar with (parts of) homological algebra. I'm possibly missing something obvious, but I don't see the construction explicitly. This probably doesn't come from the same construction that gives us long exact sequences from short exact sequences of chain complexes. Everything would work out perfectly if $0\to \text{Hom}(A,G')\to \text{Hom}(A,G)\to \text{Hom}(A,G'')\to 0$ was exact, but it's not

Comment: For instance, when constructing long exact sequences, you'd only consider homology or cohomology groups. However, in this case, you're considering the original groups themselves. So the only remaining option is that homology (or cohomology) groups are the full $\text{Hom}(A,G)$ sets, which seems strange

Comment: I can sketch what I know using the definitions I am familiar with. We define $\operatorname{Ext}^n (A,B)$ by taking a projective resolution of $A$, homming into $B$ then taking the nth cohomology. Thus, if I have a short exact sequence of abelian groups, I can take projective resolutions and since this functor is exact, I have a short exact sequence of projective resolutions. For a projective chain complex, homming out is exact, so when I take hom with $B$ I still have a SES of cochain complexes. Take the LES of cohomology. By definition of Ext, we have the LES you want.

Comment: The injective version will be analogous.